# Receiving "unmatched pseudo-class :lang" after updating Angular

Tags: css, node.js, angular

After updating node, I started receiving the following error:

> custom-file-input:lang(en)~.custom-file-label -> unmatched pseudo-class :lang

I am not understanding what the issue is. How can I sort out this error? I installed node 14.X.

Comment: Are you using any third-party CSS libraries, such as Twitter Bootstrap, with your Angular application? Or JavaScript components which might generate CSS? Or is all of your CSS created by you (or your team)?

Comment: Also, your title says you upgraded Angular, but your body says you upgraded node. Did you upgrade both? Did you isolate it down to either node or Angular? If you upgraded Angular, what version did you upgrade from and to? That information will help future readers understand if they have the same issue.

Answer (score 9):

That is probably due to the fact that the `:lang()` selector is deprecated in this new version of Angular, you could try this instead:

```
[lang="en"] {
    // Your code
}

[lang="fr"] {
    // Your code
}
```

Comment: It’s worth noting that CSS libraries or JavaScript components that write CSS might be using the legacy pseudoclass as well, and may need to be updated. As [@dmitry-kholodov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16018359/dmitry-kholodov) notes, for example, this issue may appear with Twitter Bootstrap 4, and can be fixed by upgrading to the beta of Twitter Bootstrap 5. Obviously, each library may need to be evaluated if you aren’t writing all of your CSS.

Comment: Can someone supply a reference for when/why this happened? I'm not finding anything about it online.

Answer (score 8):

I have the same warning after upgrading node to v12 and Angular from 11 to 12. After some digging I found `:lang(en)` in Bootstrap v4.6.0.. Since it is not an error but a warning I am going to ignore it. But the only way to rid off of it is to wait for Bootstrap upgrade.

Answer (score 6):

After updating my project from Angular 11 to 12 a while ago, I did a build for production for the first time today. I notized the `"unmatched pseudo-class :lang"` -warning, and found a thread on the subject at mdboostrap.com. One of the staff members recommended this solution:

In angular.json replace `"optimization":true` with this:

```
"optimization": {
  "scripts": true,
  "styles": {
    "minify": true,
    "inlineCritical": false
  },
  "fonts": true
}
```

I am not sure exactly what this does, but it removed the warning for me.

[Angular 12 production build warning (MDB4 12) - Material Design for Bootstrap](https://mdbootstrap.com/support/angular/angular-12-production-build-warning-mdb4-12/)

Comment: This didn't work for me in Angular 15

Answer (score 5):

When we upgrade our application to Angular 12 we recived the same error (Angular 12 with Bootstrap 4) also.

UI developer from my team solved this error by override bootstrap selector like below:

```
$custom-file-text: ();
```

This code put to `_bootstrap.scss` file.

I hope this hint helps you.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed with bootstrap 5.x for angular 12.

Answer (score 2):

use `$custom-file-text: ();` before import bootstrap

```
$custom-file-text: (); // --> Warning: 1 rules skipped due to selector errors: .custom-file-input:lang(en) ~ .custom-file-label -> unmatched pseudo-class :lang
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

Answer (score 1):

I had local version of Bootstrap 4.0.0 save in css directory, resolved it by removing it from the file (Not the best practice but resolved the warning for me)

```
.custom-file-input:lang(en)~.custom-file-label::after{content:"Browse"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Removed this warning by replacing

```
.custom-file-input:lang(en) ~ .custom-file-label::after {
  content: "Browse";
 }
```

with

```
.custom-file-input ~ .custom-file-label::after {
  content: "Browse";
}
```

from

`node_modules -> bootstrap -> dist -> css -> bootstrap.css` File.

(not sure if this is the correct way since lang() is deprecated so i removed it)